# Python teniendo problemas con los "IF's"

Tags: python, visual-studio, condiciones

Alguien tiene alguna idea de que es lo que debo de hacer en este caso? En la linea 12 no me permite ejecutar el programa debido a un "tab" no esperado....
[image: No tengo la menor idea de que hacer soy relativamente nuevo en esto de python...]

Comment: 2 recomendaciones: por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estas en SO en español ya que en caso contrario tu preguntaterminará cerrada, finalmente por favor coloca tu código como texto y no como imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltan los dos puntos al final del `if` y del `elif` (al final de la línea).

Al interpretar la línea 12, como no tiene los dos puntos `:`, no espera un *indent* en la siguiente línea

Comment: Considera porfavor no responder a preguntas redactadas en otro idioma ya que casi seguro termine cerrada si el OP no la traduce

Comment: Nuevo usuario, no dudo que pronto la corrija en español

Comment: Muchas gracias!